# Which of the following conditions imply that this convergence is uniform?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, uniform-convergence

let $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$be a sequence of continuous functions defined on $[0, 1]$. Assume
that $f_n(x) \rightarrow f(x)$ for every $x ∈ [0, 1]$. Which of the following conditions imply that this convergence is uniform?

$a.$ The function f is continuous.

$b.$ $f_n(x) ↓ f(x)$ for every $x ∈ [0, 1].$

$c.$ The function $f$ is continuous and $f_n(x) ↓ f(x)$ for every $x ∈ [0, 1].$

i  thinks  all  option  a) , b)  and c)  are true take $f(x) = -e^x$  strictly  decreasing  monotonics

Is its correct ???

Comment: a) is false. The standard  "growing steeple" function is a counterexample!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Only c) is correct; it follows from [Dini's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dini%27s_theorem).

Option a) is false. Just take $f\colon[0,1]\longrightarrow\mathbb R$ as the null function and$$f_n(x)=\begin{cases}x&\text{ if }x=\frac1n\\0&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$And option b) is false too. Take $f_n\colon[0,1]\longrightarrow\mathbb R$ defined by $f_n(x)=x^n$. It converges pointwise (but *not* uniformly) to$$f(x)=\begin{cases}0&\text{ if }x<1\\1&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$

Comment: @ jose carlos  $f_n(x) ↓ f(x)$  for every $x ∈ [0, 1]$.....i mean  here  function  f is  decreasing,, as Im not  getting ur option $ b)$ as  ur  given  function is not decreasing

Comment: For each $x\in[0,1]$, the sequence $(x^n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ **is** decreasing.

Comment: @ jose  carlos  sir Thanks  u